# Fire that turns to smoke

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, physics, smoke-simulation, fire

I want to make a stream of fire where drips of it fall off, and then it turns into thick smoke.  How can I do that?

[image: Example].

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Step 1. [Learn to make fire and smoke.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=blender+cycles+fire+smoke+tutorial) Step 2. Make a particle system that will emit the dripping off bits.